# How to make CounterUp jQuery plugin run only once?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am using a pretty popular jQuery counter plugin to add some more functionality to a site that I am building. The plugin runs great and I am not getting any errors but the plugin runs whenever you scroll down to it. The issue is I want it to run only once no matter how many times you scroll over it, unless the page is refreshed of course. The plugin uses Waypoints.js to activate it's counter function and I am using a CDN to call both of them. I am just curious if there is anyway to possibly just make it run once... any help is appreciated.

My function is simple but goes as follows:

```
$('.bold').counterUp({
delay: 10,
time:   1000,
triggerOnce:true
})
```

The trigger once is obviously not working. The HTML goes as follows:

```
<p class"bold">200</p>
```

and it is wrapped in a document.ready() script.

I have no idea if the problem lies in Waypoints or JS but there is almost no documentation on how to run the counter only once...

Comment: Is `triggerOnce` even an option?  If this is the plugin you're using, I don't see it https://github.com/bfintal/Counter-Up

Comment: I attempted to use it just to see if it would work knowing that it wasn't really an option because I've tried so many different things... nothing seems to work.

Comment: Anyhow, even without `triggerOnce`,  running the [`demo`](http://bfintal.github.io/Counter-Up/demo/demo.html) only runs the counter one time.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that... I have no idea how it runs once. I have seen multiple people complain that it runs more than once though. I've used it before on another website and it runs whenever you scroll up and scroll back down to it.

Comment: Hmm, can you post a running snippet of the behavior?  Are you using the same version of waypoint.js on the demo page?  Same version of counterUp?

Comment: Yep I can post a fiddle, give me a sec. And yep I'm using the most recent CDN for both.

Comment: Ok, btw take a read here [`here`](https://github.com/bfintal/Counter-Up/issues/16) and [`here`](https://github.com/ciromattia/jquery.counterup/issues/5).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ah6muksy/11/ here is the fiddle!

Comment: Btw I viewed those links and they didn't really offern any solutions, they basically only stated that they 'fixed' the issue but in reality it's still broken...

Comment: Just ran your fiddle and confirmed what you're seeing.  Looks like a bug in the plugin.  The console shows `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shift' of null`.

Comment: Any clue on how to fix it, it's preventing me from completing this website and it needs to be done by tomorrow...

Comment: Did you see this comment there _"What i did to fix this issue, i changed my waypoints version to match the one on the demo which is version 2.0.3."_ .  Link [`here`](https://github.com/ciromattia/jquery.counterup/issues/5#issuecomment-317403887).

Comment: I'll try it right now!

Comment: Now it doesn't function at all...

Comment: I updated your fiddle and it's working perfectly now https://jsfiddle.net/fg2La1gj/1/

Comment: I downgraded to jQuery `v1.12.4` and waypoints `v2.0.3` and it works like a charm now.

Comment: Isn't it bad practice to downgrade versions from the most current version...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get your counter working properly, unfortunately you need to downgrade waypoints to `v2.0.3`.  I also downgraded jQuery to `v1.12.4`.  I agree downgrading is bad practice but in the meantime you can submit an issue request on [github](https://github.com/bfintal/Counter-Up/issues).

Also you can try experimenting with different versions to see the highest versions you can use that don't produce the bug.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.bold').counterUp({
    delay: 10,
    time: 1000,
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.3/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Counter-Up/1.0.0/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>


<div class="one"></div>

<div class="two">
  <p class="bold">100</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Really sucks having to downgrade but I guess it does solve the problem, absolutely terrible plugin because there is no documentation and very few options with their scripts. Thanks though!

Comment: @MXM97  You're welcome.  Btw, thanks for marking this as the correct answer.  You can also upvote as well.

Comment: @MXM97 Ahhh, there's a reason why this plugin is so outdated.  It's because it's from an old fork.  The updated project is [`here`](https://github.com/ciromattia/jquery.counterup) with better features. It might be worthwhile to use the updated plugin and ditch the old one.  That way you can use more recent versions of jQuery and waypoints.

Comment: I ended up using the updated version and it works beautifully, thank you so much for all of your help. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you use waypoints.js 3.0 - 4.0.1 you can change string:

```
$this.waypoint(counterUpper, { offset: '100%', triggerOnce: true });
```

to

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
            element: $this,
            handler: function (direction) {
                counterUpper();
                this.destroy()
            },
            offset: '100%'
        })
```

In jquery.counterup.js file

Answer (score -1):

At first to fix counter up issue for not counting or decreases Counter-Up decreases after scrolling the page watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsuwuFU-8H4

Hopefully everything will work well if you have issue comment it below

Comment: Please don't link youtube videos but summarize their content in textual form.