# Jquery counter with decimal on scrolling animated

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Why when I make a scrolling for the page the value of the counter changes and does not remain fixed? "animated jquery"

```
  
>! jquery links 

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Counter-Up/1.0.0/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
```

```
The counter

    <h2 class="counter">11.40</h2>
    <h2 class="counter">3.40</h2>
    <h2 class="counter">5.40</h2>
    <h2 class="counter">43.40</h2>
    <h2 class="counter">41.40</h2>
```

```
>! I want the value to not change when I scroll the page
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".counter").counterUp({
            delay: 100,
            time: 1200
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001063/how-to-make-counterup-jquery-plugin-run-only-once) answer your question?